# Firestore: merge 2 Streams and emit both values

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 Firestore Queries and want to merge them in to a single Stream that can be displayed using a StreamBuilder.

StreamGroup isn't for me, because it only emits the values of the latest emited stream. StreamZip also isn't for me because it Zips the values of the Stream like title & post, but the length of the returned QueryResult could be not equal to the other and both streams would stop if the shortest Stream goes out of indexes.

Here some dummy/pseudo code:

```
Stream query1 = Some FirestoreQuery; 
Stream query2 = Some FirestoreQuery;

Stream mergedQuerys = merge([Query1, Query2])

mergedQuerys.listen((mergedQueryDocs) {
   print(mergedQueryDocs)
})

query1.emit([1,2,3])
//Output should be => [1,2,3]

query2.emit([4,5,6])
//Output should be => [1,2,3,4,5,6]

query1.emit([])
//Output should be => [4,5,6]
```

I just want to merge them and if one of the 2 basis Stream emits it should emit both values to the new Stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package for that:

```dart
Stream query1 = Stream.fromIterable([1,2,3]);
Stream query2 = Stream.fromIterable([4,5,6]);

// Will emit all items in query1, then all items in query2.
Stream mergedQueries = Observable.concat([query1, query2]);

// Will emit all items in query1 or query2, whichever item comes first.
Stream mergedQueries = Observable.merge([query1, query2]);
```

Which operator to select depends on whether you want to preserve strict order. But in case of using `concat` `query1` will have to terminate prior to `query2` be able to emit items. So for the case with (probably) endless query subscriptions I think you should go with `merge` operator – when either of `query1` or `query2` streams emits items, it will be emitted by `mergedQueries`.

Comment: thank you so much for trying to help me! I've tried both solutions with a StreamBuilder Widget and i get the same result. Can it be that the StreamBuilder is blocking me from archiving what i want?

Comment: @MarcMa can you provide your widget's code and the expected/actual result? Otherwise it's hard to tell what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Again thank you for helping. But i solved it now.

My Solution:
Subscribe to the 2 Streams in initState(), make 2 Lists that gets rendered in order in a ListView. Make those 2 Streams update the other Lists and call setState(). Dont forget to close Streams!

StreamBuilder only picked the value of the latest emitting stream, which is an unexpected behavior...